# finding the view id in my google analytics dashboard

Tags: google-analytics, laravel-8

am trying to use Google analytics on my laravel project so I can see the statistics of visitors and am trying to set it up on my project with this  [tutorial](https://codelapan.com/post/google-analytics-laravel#mcetoc_1f87pg3kai), so I did everything but when I needed the view_id I couldn't find it in my dashboard.

Comment: If you are using Google analytics GA4 it does not have view ids. You wont find one.  If this is the case then please edit your question and describe what it is exactly you are trying to do with Google analytics and larval.

Comment: thank you for your reply, so where can I find it ?